# MYSQL Get last record on alphanumeric sort

Tags: mysql

How can I get the last record of this table:

```
id  trans_type  trans_date  reference_no
5804    RFBI    20151214    RFBI-20151214-1
5806    RFBI    20151214    RFBI-20151214-2
5809    RFBI    20151214    RFBI-20151214-3
5814    RFBI    20151214    RFBI-20151214-4
5818    RFBI    20151214    RFBI-20151214-5
5822    RFBI    20151214    RFBI-20151214-7
5823    RFBI    20151214    RFBI-20151214-8
5824    RFBI    20151214    RFBI-20151214-9
5825    RFBI    20151214    RFBI-20151214-10
5826    RFBI    20151214    RFBI-20151214-11
5827    RFBI    20151214    RFBI-20151214-12
5828    RFBI    20151214    RFBI-20151214-13
5821    RFBI    20151214    RFBI-20151214-14
5835    RFBI    20151214    RFBI-20151214-15
```

I can sort using this query.

```
SELECT id,`trans_type`,`trans_date`,`reference_no`
FROM (`tbl_transaction` as trans)
WHERE (`trans_type` =  'RFBI'
AND `trans`.`trans_date` =  '20151214')
ORDER BY LENGTH(reference_no), `reference_no`
```

I need to get the last reference_no

```
   5835 RFBI    20151214    RFBI-20151214-15
```

I was thinking this query

```
SELECT id,`trans_type`,`trans_date`,`reference_no`
FROM (`tbl_transaction` as trans)
WHERE (`trans_type` =  'RFBI'
AND `trans`.`trans_date` =  '20151214')
ORDER BY LENGTH(reference_no), `reference_no` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

but the result is:

```
5824    RFBI    20151214    RFBI-20151214-9
```

Comment: try using either DESC or ASC in your ORDER BY area, then use LIMIT 0,1 may help

Comment: Did you try `ORDER BY reference_no DESC` ?

Comment: I think the column, reference_no, needs to be enhanced if it will be used as a filter/identifier for a certain record or group set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `DESC` twice in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT id, trans_type, trans_date, reference_no
FROM `tbl_transaction` trans
WHERE `trans_type` =  'RFBI' AND `trans`.`trans_date` =  '20151214'
ORDER BY LENGTH(reference_no) DESC, `reference_no` DESC
------------------------------^
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
select id, trans_type, trans_date, reference_no
from tbl_transaction
where trans_type = 'RFBI'
and trans_date = '20151214'
order by id desc 
limit 1
```

Another way of doing the same thing would be to remove all but the actual numeric reference number at the end like so (but performance may be something to watch out for...I'm just providing additional method of doing the same thing)

```
select id, trans_type, trans_date, reference_no
from tbl_transaction
where trans_type = 'RFBI'
and trans_date = '20151214'
order by cast(replace(reference_no, concat(trans_type,'-',trans_date,'-'), '') as unsigned) desc
limit 1
```

In this method above we are leveraging the fact that reference_no is made up of trans_type and trans_date combined with dashes. We remove those, leaving just the number part and convert the number to an unsigned integer. We sort by it highest-first and take the first record.

That leads to a recommendation - could you not just store an integer in reference_no column? That way your sorting will be so much easier and your storage requirement will drop to an integer (4 bytes). Your index on it will be smaller also. When `select`ing data, you could just `concat` trans_type, trans_date and the reference no.